# How to redirect the output of fuser to a file?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, redirect, fuser

I'm using `fuser` with options `-uv` and I'm getting following output:

```
$fuser -uv ~/sh/test_script.sh

                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/home/abc/sh/test_script.sh:
                     abc        3501 f.... (abc)test_script.sh
```

However, when I try to redirect the output of the command I'm only getting PID in the file:

```
$fuser -vu ~/sh/test_script.sh >> t2.txt

                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/home/abc/sh/test_script.sh:
                     abc       f.... (abc)test_script.sh

$cat t2.txt
3501
```

Why is it not including all the information during output redirection?

Also, how to include all the information during output redirection?

Using `lsof` I'm able to redirect all the information to a file.

Comment: Try: `fuser -uv some_file >output.txt 2>&1`

Comment: According to `man fuser`: `fuser outputs only the PIDs to stdout, everything else is sent to stderr.`

Comment: @xxfelixxx: Thanks for the help!